# Postgres: convert fetched table name to an actually usable table name

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Is there a way to make this request work?
I want to fetch a table name from a table and then use that table name in the same sql to fetch  all data from that dependent table.

```sql
select dt.*
    from tree_node as tn
inner join tree_node_type as tnt
    on tnt.id = tn.type_id
inner join tnt.table_name as dt
    on dt.id = tn.id
```

Upon trying this query today Postgres fails saying that relation 'tnt.table_name' doesn't exist. How do I make it use that column's value as a table name?

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL if you want to use table names stored as string values.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ok thank you, I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

If the table structure is known to all tables, you could use a function like this:

Data Sample

```
CREATE TABLE t (tbname TEXT);
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('t2'),('t3'); --name of tables created below 

CREATE TABLE t2 (rec TEXT);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES ('foo-t2'),('bar-t2');

CREATE TABLE t3 (rec TEXT);
INSERT INTO t3 VALUES ('foo-t3'),('bar-t3');
```

Function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getrecords(text) 
RETURNS TABLE (rec TEXT) LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM %I',$1);
END$$;
```

Note that the functions return a table with a single column, so you need to adjust the amount and type of the returning columns.
Query

```
SELECT getrecords(t.tbname) FROM t;

 getrecords 
------------
 foo-t2
 bar-t2
 foo-t3
 bar-t3
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5c379aa6a4e6a3118c900ce0229e8600)